# In F#, is there a way to simplify this wrapper for OpenFile and SaveFile dialogs'

Tags: f#, functional-programming, inline

```
type MyOpenFileDialog(dg: OpenFileDialog) =
  member x.ShowDialog = dg.ShowDialog
  member x.OpenFile = dg.OpenFile

type MySaveFileDialog(dg: SaveFileDialog) =
  member x.ShowDialog = dg.ShowDialog
  member x.OpenFile = dg.OpenFile
```

The following indicated 'T (^T) would escape it's scope:

```
type MyFileDialog<'T 
  when 
    'T : (member OpenFile:unit->Stream) and 
    'T : (member ShowDialog:unit->Nullable<bool>)
  >(dg: 'T) =
  member x.ShowDialog = dg.ShowDialog
  member x.OpenFile = dg.op
```

Note, the constraint expression `MyFileDialog<'T...>(dg: 'T)=` should all be on one line. Is split for clarity (should be allowed in language I think :) )

Comment: The problem is that `member` constraints need to be on `inline` functions, you can't encode them in the .net tpye system, so they escape the definition

Answer (score 4):

Static member constraints let you do quite a lot of things, but they are somewhat cumbersome (they work well for generic numerical computations, but not so well as a general-purpose abstraction). So, I would be careful about using them.

Anyway, if you want to do this, then you can - to some point. As John mentioned in the comments, code that uses static member constraints need to be `inline`. But you can make that a static member, which captures the operations that your type uses:

```
type MyFileDialog
    private(openFile:unit -> Stream, showDialog : unit -> DialogResult) =
  member x.OpenFile() = openFile()
  member x.ShowDialog() = showDialog()
  static member inline Create(dg : ^T) =
    MyFileDialog
      ( (fun () -> (^T : (member OpenFile:unit -> Stream) dg)),
        (fun () -> (^T : (member ShowDialog:unit -> DialogResult) dg)) )

let d1 = MyFileDialog.Create(new OpenFileDialog())
let d2 = MyFileDialog.Create(new SaveFileDialog())
```

Comment: Wow. That's some jujitsu. Nice. Thanks Tomas. The solution I proceeded with shortly after posting is a lot more verbose and so I may rewrite it. That approach was to use an interface (`IMyFileDialog` not list the required features) and then object expressions to pass the various implementations: `{new IMyFileDialog with ...}`